# Userform to only appear on first use #excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel

So I made a questionnaire on excel that contains a userform when the workbook opens (so when you open excel). The userform makes the user choose the language he wants to use (French or English). My problem is that I would like the userform to only pop up the first time the user opens the file. So he opens the file, chooses the language, answers the questions and saves the file. I would like for him/her to not choose the language again if he re-opens the file.

Is there a way to make the userform only appear on first use?

If not, I'm thinking about changing the value in a certain box in the questionnaire when it opens and then link that value to the userform so it doesn't open the next time if the value has changed. I don't know if that's possible either.

Thank you for your help,

Vincent

Comment: You can set a value in, say, a hidden sheet after you fill out the questionnaire. You can check this sheet for a value on load, if it has a value you'll know the form has been filled out before.

Comment: Yeah good idea thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common and easy way would be to have a hidden worksheet where you can use cells to store values after saves.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Where HiddenSheet is the name of your hidden worksheet
    If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("HiddenSheet").Cells(1, 1).Value = 0 Then
        'Code to open the form
    End If    
End Sub
```

And then once the user has completed the question are you can alter the cell value so it doesn't open again.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("HiddenSheet").Cells(1, 1).Value = 1
```

Comment: Yeah good idea.
So basically a HiddeSheet is a sheet neither I or the user will have access to?
Can I change the cell value say in A1 in that sheet when the user saves the file? @Alex

Comment: @petithomme yep, a sheet which you can hide and password lock. You'll have access to it, but the user will not see or know it's there. You can choose any cell for any kind of settings or data you want to keep.

Comment: Oh cool and I imagine that in the code you've written below the sheet's name was "HiddenSheet". So I can name it the way I want but insert the correct name in the code?

Comment: @petithomme Exactly.

Comment: Last question @Alex D    In your Cells(1, 1), the first one indicates the line or column?

Comment: @petithomme Cells(Row, Column)

Answer (score 0):

I like using this statement in the worksheet I want to hide.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If ActiveSheet.Visible Then ActiveSheet.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Basically the user can try and unhide the sheet, but it immediately hides it again. Of course you'll still need a password to protect the code, but I've found it helpful to prevent showing users information they don't need to worry about.

Thought I'd add this as it seems to relate to part of the question. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Oh ok I'll check it out.
Right now I'm just using the protect the workbook function so users just don't have access before removing the protection first.

Comment: if you want to really hide the sheet, you can set its `Visible` property to `xlSheetVeryHidden` instead of  `False`

Comment: I didn't know that, nice!

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way is to keep a log of all users who access the file using:

```
Application.Username()
```

or

```
Environ()
```

functions.

Then using Workbook.Open event, run a code to:

1. Loop through a user log on a hidden sheet;
2. Check if the current user exist in the log already;
3. If yes, means the user is not a new user;
4. If not, get user name and add to the log.

Just the username without date & time stamp.

It is a foolproof method with double benefit of keeping a history of all users who've ever accessed the file.